# Manga or webtoon about a guy who has this aura that can't be suppressed, and all the demons want to get him

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, demons

It's about a guy who has this aura that can't be suppressed, and all the demons want to get him. He can't leave the shrine that he has been in because of the aura he emits.

He finds out that he has a small domain and he can control anything in the small domain. When a demon was in his shrine he killed it and that's how he found out that he could expand his domain from a system (I think) by killing things in his small domain.

He also ends up getting a human disciple and 3 demon disciples. The 1st goal is to get his domain as big as the mountain that he lives on with the sect he makes.

I know that's a lot but info but I can't seem to remember the name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Why did you change the title to say that? The reason I edited the title is because we prefer the titles of story-ID questions to mention some specific plot details, rather than generically saying _"Manga I can't remember the name of"_ or whatever. Generic titles like that make it harder to tell such questions apart when searching the archives.

Comment: Also, can you clarify whether this was in full colour or mostly black & white? It could make it significantly easier to ID this story.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It's called [*Invincible at the Start*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/invincible-at-the-start).

[image: Front cover of Invincible at the Start]

> “Ding, the host has opened the invincible field! As long as the host is invincible in the field…!” As a nerd, Chen Changan travels through the fantasy world, facing countless monsters and ghosts from the outside world, Chen Changan decided not to leave his invincible field before becoming immortal. When he is bored, he occasionally raises a few cute and sweet apprentices, and accidentally cultivated them to become leaders in the spiritual world, which turned the world upside down.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to describe why this matches? And you will be able to accept by clicking on the checkmark, although as a self-answer, you have to wait 48 hours after the asking (if you click early, it will tell you how long you have left). Also, how did you find it?